# If $x+y+z^2=xy+1$ with $(y-1)^2 \ne z^2$ and $x\ne y$, then $\frac {(y-1)^2}{(y-1)^2-z^2} + \frac {x-1}{x-y}=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x+y+z^2=xy+1$ with $(y-1)^2 \ne z^2$ and  $x\ne y$:

Compute: $$\frac {(y-1)^2}{(y-1)^2-z^2} + \frac {x-1}{x-y}$$

I tried making $z^2=xy+1-x-y$ and replacing, but i didn't get results. Any hints?

Comment: $z^2 = (x-1)(y-1)$

Comment: I got the following answer:$1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg . U R right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the equation as $z^2=(x-1)(y-1)$, we can cancel a factor of $y-1$ from the first term to get
$$\frac{(y-1)^2}{(y-1)^2-z^2}=\frac{(y-1)^2}{(y-1)^2-(x-1)(y-1)}=\frac{(y-1)}{(y-1)-(x-1)}=\frac{(y-1)}{y-x}$$

We then have a common denominator, and

$$\frac{(y-1)}{y-x}+\frac{(x-1)}{x-y}=\frac{(x-1)-(y-1)}{x-y}=1.$$